# Loop is crazy - one row displays wrong count of posts

Tags: loop, count

Im having a loop with count to add a clear after 4 items. It is working pretty well but theres one rebell row that will only take 1 post.

Code:

```
            <section class="bonds-funding">
            <h1>Funders</h1>
            <?php the_field( "funding_subtitle" ); ?>

    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'institution',  ) 
        ); 
        $counter = 0;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  if ($counter % 4 == 0) :
        echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
        echo "<div class='clearfix'>";
    endif;
            $colors = get_field('institution_status');

    if( $colors && in_array('funding', $colors) ){ ?>

                <div class="author-nucleus">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_field('institution_website', $user->ID); ?>">
                                <div class="author-avatar">
                                    <!-- <div class="hexa">
                                        <div class="hex1">
                                            <div class="hex2"> -->
                                                <img src="
                                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $user->ID ); ?>" />
                                            <!-- </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> -->
                                </div>
                            </a>
                                <div class="author-info">
                                    <div class="institution-padding">
                                        <h2>
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </h2>
                                    </div>
                                        <hr />
                                        <?php
                                            echo get_field('institution_subhead', $user->ID) ?>
                                        <ul class="nucleus-icons-test">
                                        <?php
                                            $post_id = get_the_ID();
                                get_subjects($post_id, 'post', 6);
                                ?>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }
                        $counter++;
                         endwhile;
                          wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </section>
```

First 4 posts display correctly inside a div then, the next div displays only one post, then two more divs with correct count.

What the....?

Answer (score 1):

For your clearfix wrapper you are doing it wrong. You have this:

```
$counter = 0;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
if ($counter % 4 == 0) :
 echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
 echo "<div class='clearfix'>";
endif;
// BUILDS INTERNAL DIVS
$counter++;
endwhile;
```

So you are opening the div for numbers 0 and multiples of the number 4. Then inside that statement you are only closing a div if the `$counter` is greater than 0. So you end up closing the div, then opening a new one that may not get closed.

You need to do two things. First, move the closing `div` to echo at the end of the `while` statement. Second, wrap the closing `div` in a different conditional. Here it is corrected:

```
$counter = 0;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
 echo "<div class='clearfix'>";
}
// BUILDS INTERNAL DIVS

/**
 * Closing div for loop 
 *
 * $counter is more than 0 AND $counter plus 1 is multiple of 4
 * OR $counter plus 1 is the total posts found (the plus 1 here is because we start with 0 which counts toward our total)
 */
if ( ($counter > 0 && ($counter+1) % 4 == 0 ) || ($counter+1) == $loop->found_posts ) {
 echo "</div>";
}
$counter++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: thank you! I tried but having the same issue the 5th item is still alone in a div

Comment: I'm sorry. I see that in my haste posting this the conditional for the closing div is incorrect. I am looking at it real quick and will correct soon.

Comment: @CynthiaLara I fixed the mistake in the code.

Comment: Nathan, thank you I updated the code but it is still acting crazy and one row is displaying only one post - it makes no sense and I can't figure out why this happens

Comment: Is it possible that you haven't put the code in correctly? I don't know what to say, this code is correct. Have you tried just putting `the_title()` in place of all the other output in between with any results? There shouldn't be any reason for this to fail the way it is.

Comment: I know it shouldn't hehe its super crazy this is happening... I will continue to troubleshoot maybe theres something else there that's breaking it, its a little stressing this makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just:

```
<style>
.author-nucleus:nth-of-type(4):after {
    clear:both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
</style>
```

That's all you basically need in my opinion. The true beauty of css!
No need to do weired counting with opening and closing div's.

Explaination: this css-rule will add a pseudo element after four row's/div's which will clear your float.
Pro: lightweight, easyly changeable
Cons: /

Comment: thanks but tried and it gives the same result, the trouble rebel in the #5 place is giving a clear for no reason :( and also it only adds a clear after the first 2 items not resetting count after that clear